# Facebook photos in Gallery

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I've found [this simple tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/browsing-facebook-albums) that explain me how add in a gallery photos from facebook, but there is a problem.. when it downloads photos, it downloads max 25 photos (in my album there are 150 photos).

Where is the problem? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some [pagination](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/) parameters to the `facebook_url_photos` string.

Specifically, `&limit=200` should do the job.